# Three magento websites having same database

Tags: magento

I want to setup three magento websites having same database. The difference will be in the product prices but all other specifications will be the same.
The inventory will also be similar.

Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely possible, here is a overview of how its done.

http://www.crucialwebhost.com/kb/how-to-setup-multiple-magento-stores/

If you have further questions please be specific and I will attempt to answer.

If you would like developer assistance I would go with webporch.com, they are great and specialize in Magento.

If this guides you along please accept it as the answer!